# HTML5 AudioPlayer to run on Android (WebView-App) also in background mode

Tags: android, webview, media-player, html5-audio

I developed a HTML5 Media/AudioPLayer that runs on mobile devices and is able to handle playlists, etc.
I created a webview app (based on XWalk Project to replace original WebView) that works perfectly.
Now I have the problem that I want to create an Android app that is able to keep playing playlist even if the app runs in background mode.
Because the playlist logic is implemented in Javascript and the playback is done with HTML5 I cannot put playback into a service easily. Can anybody give me support?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered working with the project in PhoneGap?

I am about to investigate this PhoneGap plugin which provides background support on Android, iOS and WP8 https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/blob/ac5fef831dbf9e567277dc900389923bd9bc7714/README.md